# Using ArrayFormula with Indirect to combine sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to combine data from other sheets into a single sheet.  I thought I could use a formula to find the last row in each sheet and combine with an Indirect ArrayFormula but that doesn't work.

> Indirect("ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet1'!A2:J"&ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK ('Sheet1'!A1:A10000)),      ROW('Sheet1'!A1:A10000),0)))&";'Sheet2'!A2:J"&ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK ('Sheet2'!A1:A10000)), ROW('Sheet2'!A1:A10000),0)))})")

The Indirect and ArrayFormula combo doesn't seem to be the answer as it errors out - it appears you can't run an indirect and array formula together.

EDIT:
Using the formula above without the Indirect and finding the last blank row will combine the sheets when I keep a long row range but it keeps all the blank rows and spreads the data of each sheet out too much.

```
ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet1'!A2:J100";'Sheet2'!A2:J100)})
```

Which is why I was trying to use the max arrayformula to find the last row in each sheet to consolidate the blank rows.

```
ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK ('Sheet1'!A1:A10000)), ROW('Sheet1'!A1:A10000),0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I misunderstood your question, here's an alternative to the formula you provided..

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A:J; Sheet3!A:J}, "select * where Col1 <>'' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In a google spreadsehet, if you want to retrieve the last row of both sheets you can try:

```
={INDEX(Sheet1!A:J, MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:A))))); INDEX(Sheet2!A:J, MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet2!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A:A)))))}
```

this will put the last row of the second sheet in a row under the last row of the first sheet.
In case you want those rows to appear in the same row, try:

```
={INDEX(Sheet1!A:J, MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:A))))), INDEX(Sheet2!A:J, MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet2!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A:A)))))}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for getting me the last row in each sheet.  Looking to pull everything, so A2:J(last nonblank row) for each sheet.  So it might be A2:J9 or A2:J1000

Comment: Why not use open ended ranges like I did in the formulas above ?

Comment: Using open ended on the original formula still pulls all the rows on the entire sheet (including blank ones).  So if I have 1 header and 9 rows of data it pulls 900 blank rows before displaying the next sheet +headers

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can't use indirect outside of an arrayformula but you can use it inside { }

```
 ={INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A2:J"&MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:A))))) ; INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!A2:J"&MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet2!A:J),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A:A)))))}
```

This combines the sheets perfectly.